# Composer require is not working

Tags: php, composer-php

i have installed composer on my ubuntu.
`$php composer.phar`
 is working fine and showing all the commands,
but`'$composer require herrera-io/silex-pdo`
 giving this error.
'No command 'composer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'compose' from package 'mime-support' (main)
composer: command not found'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why do i get the error? No command 'composer' found**

You didn't define a global shortcut yet.

The command to invoke Composer without a shortcut is: `php composer.phar`

And so the command to install a package is `php composer.phar require herrera-io/silex-pdo`.

What does it do? You are using PHP to run the composer.phar file. This executes Composer with the arguments specified, here `require` and `vendor/package`.

---

You might want to shorten that line by using a global shortcut to executing composer.phar. One way of doing this, is to move the file a `bin` folder, e.g. `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`. Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Then you can type `composer` in order to run Composer instead of `php composer.phar`.

And then your command `composer require herrera-io/silex-pdo` should work.

Answer (score 1):

run this command then your composer work properly

```
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin --filename=composer
```